# Tub & Sink gurgles when toilet flushes, stops when hot water is put down either one, but have to do it every two weeks. Any solution?

Tags: plumbing

Every two weeks I have to put hot water down the tub or sink to stop the toilet flushing from making it gurgle. Is it a clog in the line or the vent on the roof?  Any suggestions please? Or is it ok to just do this every two weeks?  There is no odor.  Thank you!

Comment: You have a venting problem.  If this has been the case since the beginning it's likely poor plumbing installation.  If it's recently started then perhaps your vent has become clogged or blocked.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a grease blockage in the main line to the outside of the home. I would check your cleanout outside and see if you have any grease residue in it.

Comment: Another possible cause is tree roots invading the main line outdoors.